# sending mail from hotmail fails sometimes using c#

Tags: c#, email

I have c# code to send mail. The code is working fine for gmail,yahoo configuration. But for hotmail sometimes the mail is sent and sometimes the mail is not sent. I observed that the response time for yahoo mail is better compare to gmail. But hotmail has very poor response compare to yahoo,gmail.

What will be reason? how to configure hotmail to get good response.

this is my code to send mail :

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

        message.To.Add("user_name");
                message.From = new MailAddress("user_name");
                message.Subject = "Email Confirmation";
                message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    client.Port=587
    client.Host="smtp.live.com";

    System.Net.NetworkCredential nc = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user_name", "password");
                if (mail_server == "smtp.gmail.com" || mail_server == "smtp.live.com")
                {
                    client.EnableSsl = true;
                }
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = nc;

                Ping p = new Ping();
                bool result = false;
                int i = 10;
                do
                {

                    PingReply reply = p.Send("smtp.live.com", 587);
                    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                    {
                        result = true;
                    } Thread.Sleep(500);
                    i--;
                } while (result == false && i != 0);

                if (result == true)
                {
                    client.Send(message);
                    MessageBox.Show("Email sent successfully");                    


                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Email not sent");

                }
 }
```

Comment: ridiculous isn't it? two microsoft technologies do not co-operate well!

Comment: What error(s) do you get when it fails?

Comment: @Raghvenra - can u explain why use Ping instead of `client.Send(message)` ?

Comment: Ping is used to check response from email server. if i get response IPStatus will set to "success" state. testing the server response is the ping

Comment: @AppDeveloper I am getting the following error :  Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.3 Requested action aborted; user not authenticated

Comment: @RaghavendraDevraj - its obvious the user/pass is invalid

Comment: @RaghavendraDevraj - can i know how you are sending the username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying the above code to Send Email, it will obviously not be able to send it, I dont know for what reason you are using the `Ping` class to send email.

Fixed Code :

```
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

    message.To.Add("user_name");
    message.From = new MailAddress("user_name");
    message.Subject = "Email Confirmation";
    message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    message.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    client.Port = 587;
    client.Host = "smtp.live.com";

    NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("user_name", "password");
    string mail_server = "smtp.live.com";
    if (mail_server == "smtp.gmail.com" || mail_server == "smtp.live.com")
        {
            client.EnableSsl = true;
        }
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = nc;

    try
    {
        client.Send(message);
    }
    catch (SmtpException exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
    }
```

Comment: This code is working fine... but if is use ping i am not getting response from hotmail server sometimes. ping is also used to check whether username,password is correct to send mail. I have to validate for correct mail account and display alert that "user account is not valid".

Comment: Vote for my question .. if question is valid :-)